# Create UIInteraction Script from commandline for testing iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, ios-ui-automation

I Gone through UIAutomator in the xcode Instruments tab for testing the iOS apps . I want to know whether we can record the test steps from real device and save the javascript to some specific directory  like UIAutomator from commandline without starting the Xcode .

Comment: you could try this http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation

Comment: that is done by opening xcode ...  i want it to be completely run from command line

Comment: I don't think the record feature of Instruments is available via command line. I think you are only able to call instruments and pass it a trace template to run.